# Finding generating function and closed formula

Tags: solution-verification, generating-functions

Find generating function and closed formula  $1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,...$

Solution Attempt)

$$\begin{align}G(x) &=  1 + 0x + 1x^2 + 0x^3 + 1x^4 + 0x^5 + 1 x^6 + 0 x^7 + 1 x^8 + \dots\\
&= 1 + x^2  + x^4  + x^6 +   x^8 + \dots\end{align}$$

$$G(x) =  \sum_{k = 0}^{∞} x^{2k} = \sum_{k = 0}^{∞} (x^{2})^k = \frac{1}{1-x^2}$$

Comment: Looks OK to me for the generating function. "Closed formula" may be asking for a function $f$ such that $f(n)$ is the $n$th term.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've already made this simple observation:

$$a_n=n~\text{mod}~2=n - 2 \left\lfloor \frac n2 \right\rfloor$$

But, this is the formula that sounds more lovable to me:
(just a little observation is enough to construct this formula)

$$a_n = \frac 12 \left((-1)^{n+1} + 1\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Following Ethan remark, we have

$$u_{2n}=1=|\sin((2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2})|$$
and

$$u_{2n+1}=0=|\sin((2n+2)\frac{\pi}{2})|$$

So, we can take
$$f(x)=|\sin((x+1)\frac{\pi}{2})|$$